# migrating accent color in flutter v2.5

Tags: flutter, migrating

after the flutter 2.5 update my theme data kinda broke and doesn't accept accentColor anymore. I took a look at the documantation and saw that is "renamed" to colorScheme.secondary. But no matter what I try, I can't get it to work for me.

This is my current code:

```dart
class Themes {
  static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
    accentColor: Palette.orange,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(),
    floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
      backgroundColor: Palette.orange,
      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
  );

  static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
    accentColor: Palette.orange,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(),
    floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
      backgroundColor: Palette.orange,
      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
  );
}
```

Comment: the same issue with the accentColor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many changes are in flutter 2.5

Try to use Below code hope it's helpful to you

```dart
 theme: ThemeData(
      colorScheme:  Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: Color(accentColor))
),
```

for more information check official documentation [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties)

```dart
final ThemeData theme = ThemeData();
MaterialApp(
  theme: theme.copyWith(
    colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: myColor),
  ),
  //...
)
```

Code before migration:

```
Color myColor = Theme.of(context).accentColor;
```

Code after migration:

```
Color myColor = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;
```

Comment: Also tried a similar approach after reading the docs but that exact setup throws errors

Comment: Ok what was the error and also accept the Android license

Comment: I can't use the context keyword and neither my custom color:
https://pastebin.com/ixTJBhk7