# accentColor is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Tags: flutter

The `accentColor` in `ThemeData` was deprecated.

What to use then in `ThemeData`?

```
theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: kBaseColor,
    accentColor: kBaseAccentColor, // 'accentColor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used
```

Comment: Use colorScheme Instead of accentColor **colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(accentColor: kBaseAccentColor)**

Comment: Try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69160210/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`accentColor` is now replaced by `ColorScheme.secondary`.

- **Using new `ThemeData`:**

  ```dart
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
      secondary: Colors.red, // Your accent color
    ),
  )
  ```
- **Using existing `ThemeData`:**

  ```dart
  final theme = ThemeData.dark();
  ```

  You can use it as:

  ```dart
  theme: theme.copyWith(
    colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(
      secondary: Colors.red,
    ),
  )
  ```

Comment: This one worked for me with the new ThemeData, but I had to add the parameter `brightness: Brightness.dark,`. Otherwise, Flutter gives an error without it.

Answer (score 55):

Use the below code instead of **accentColor: kBaseAccentColor,**

```
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch()
            .copyWith(secondary: kBaseAccentColor),
```

**OR**

Do this in a simple way:
Click on Magic Bulb
[image]

Click on **Migrate to 'ColorScheme.secondary'** it will automatically be converted.

[image]

Comment: you can access the colour as Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary

Answer (score 5):

Write this:

```
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch()
            .copyWith(secondary: kBaseAccentColor),
```

Then, use

> colorScheme.secondary

in place of

> accentColor

everywhere.

Comment: This looks the same as the top answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

Code before migration:

> Color myColor = Theme.of(context).accentColor;

Code after migration:

> Color myColor = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;

Answer (score 3):

As the deprecated message says:

```dart
///colorScheme.secondary
 ThemeData(colorScheme: ColorScheme(secondary:Colors.white ),);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a color scheme because accent color is deprecated.

```
body: const Center(child: const Text('BMI Calculator')),
  floatingActionButton: Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
      colorScheme:
          ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Colors.white),
    ),
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      child: const Icon(
        Icons.add,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ),
```