# Flutter : How to set Checkbox and Switch color in the Theme

Tags: flutter, checkbox, themes

In VSCode, Flutter is complaining to me that "`'accentColor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use colorScheme.secondary instead. For more information, consult the migration guide at https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties#migration-guide. This feature was deprecated after v2.3.0-0.1.pre.. Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.`"

The migration guide suggests this :

Code before migration:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(accentColor: myColor),
  // ...
);
```

Code after migration:

```dart
final ThemeData theme = ThemeData();
MaterialApp(
  theme: theme.copyWith(
    colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: myColor),
  ),
  //...
)
```

So I made this change :

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
+    final ThemeData theme = ThemeData();
     return MaterialApp(
       title: 'Title',
-      theme: ThemeData(
-        primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(95, 53, 90, 1),
-        accentColor: Color.fromRGBO(76, 41, 71, 1)
+      theme: theme.copyWith(
+        colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(
+          primary: Color.fromRGBO(95, 53, 90, 1),
+          secondary: Color.fromRGBO(76, 41, 71, 1),
         ),
+      ),
       home: MyApp()
     );
   }
```

But now my checkboxes and switches have changed from my primary colour to blue.

Can I still set the colour of my checkboxes in the theme ?

Comment: This answer can help you. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289005/accentcolor-is-deprecated-and-shouldnt-be-used

Answer (score 1):

The `Checkbox`, along with a few other widgets, still don't migrate to Material 3 scheme. There's already an open issue [#104446](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104446). The pull request [#97972](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/97972) seems will fix this.

Currently, you can orerride `toggleableActiveColor` in `ThemeData` to achieve this.