# Flutter Substitute for accentColor

Tags: flutter, themes, darkmode, lightmode

I trying to make a light theme and a dark theme for my app, I making an course of flutter and the code it's a little out of date and some commands doesn't work in the actual version of Flutter, in special the `Themedata.accentColor` or just `accentColor` who is deprecated in the last Flutter version.

I tried to search for a solution and I found two of them, one in the [Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties#migration-guide) and other on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289005/accentcolor-is-deprecated-and-shouldnt-be-used) of StackOverflow. I tried both of solutions but I still getting the same error

Error message:

```
Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart': Failed assertion: line 412 pos 12: 'colorScheme?.brightness == null || brightness == null || colorScheme!.brightness == brightness': is not true.)
```

Code:

```
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
  secondary: Colors.white,
),
```

My code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const brightness = Brightness.dark;
Color primaryColor = const Color(0xFF00C569);
Color lightColor = const Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
Color backgroundColor = const Color(0xFFF5F5F5);
Color dangerColor = const Color(0xFFFF0000);

ThemeData darkTheme() {
  return ThemeData(
    brightness: brightness,
    //iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
    //textTheme: const TextTheme(
      /*
      bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
      headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 78),
      headline2: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 30,
      ),
      button: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
    ),
    */
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
      secondary: Colors.white,
    ),
    primaryColor: primaryColor,
  );
}
```

Comment: Try `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually discovered a temporary solution for this.
The problem was a possible null value, so the code don't work. The solution basically put a `?` after the ColorScheme.
For example:

```
colorScheme: ColorScheme?.fromSwatch().copyWith(
      secondary: Colors.white,
    ),
```

if still doesn't work, try to add the brightness in the color scheme, for example:

```
colorScheme: ColorScheme?.fromSwatch().copyWith(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      secondary: Colors.white,
    ),
```